# adding attributes to a T4 preprocessor class

Tags: c#, t4

Suppose I have a T4 template TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor (that generates a class that generates an output): is it possible to add an attribute to the generator class (NOT inside the output itself)?
Basically I want something like this:

```
#line 1 "C:\Path\To\MyTemplate.tt"
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating", "11.0.0.0")]
[MyAttributeHere]
public partial class MyTemplate : MyTemplateBase
{
    // ...
```

I know I could create another file with another partial declaration of that template, and add the attribute on that, but well I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to provide your own custom tool to replace `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor`.

[image: Custom Tool property]

I imagine you would subclass `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TemplatedPreprocessor` and override `ProcessTemplate()`.

Comment: Uh, that's an interesting idea. How do you actually register a custom tool? What do you supply, an exe?

Comment: No, a dll. And you [register it with Visual Studio as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166527.aspx). There is more information here [in the section Custom Tool](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/11/t4-toolbox-automatic-template-transformation/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS 2012, then this is possible using a simple custom directive processor.
Use the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668) to create a simple MEF component extension for Visual Studio (use something like an editor colorizer template).  Delete the code that the template provides and replace it with a trivial class that provides a mostly no-op implementation of `IDirectiveProcessor` interface from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.11.0.dll`

Emit your attributes in an implementation of the `GetTemplateClassCustomAttributes` method of that interface.

Finally, decorate your class with the `[DirectiveProcessor]` and `[SuppportedDirective]` attributes from the same assembly, so that T4 picks up the new directive processor.

When you build, you should get a VSIX that you can deploy easily to any machine where you need this new directive supported at generation time.  Put the new directive at the top of your template and your attribute(s) will be added to your preprocessed class. Something like:

> `<#@ MyCustomAttr processor="MyCode.CustomAttrProvider" #>`